# Why is a custom post type's URL "/?cposts=name-of-the-post" but default post's URL is "/?p=ID"?

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, urls

The normal posts, whose `post_type` is "post" in the database, are accessed through the URL structure of `www.blog.com/?p=ID` where ID is the actual ID (the number) of the post found in the database.

But I've created a custom post type ("cpost") using the `register_post_type` function and when I create a new post of that type ("cpost") and wordpress gives me a link to access it, it is of the URL structire `www.blog.com/?cposts=name-of-the-custom-post`.

Why this difference? And how to tell wordpress to use the same URL structure to access posts of either types? (by their ID)

Answer (score 0):

For normal posts you can set the permalink structure on Settings → Permalinks.
All details can be found in the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

For custom post types you can set the slug when you registering it:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
function create_posttype() {
  register_post_type( 'cpost',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'cpost' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'cpost' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'rewrite'         => array(
          'slug'      => 'cpost',
          'with_front'  => true
        ),
    )
  );
}
```

Hope that helps,
Cheers